# Moodle: Add variable in 'a href' links in mail template

Tags: email, url, moodle

I have one short question for a hrev link in moodle mail template. When you are subscript to some forum, moodle start to send you a emails from every replay with content where you also have a href links. How can I add same variable in a href link in moodle mail. Explanation, if I reply to some forum , I received email where I have link http://moodle.com/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=132 , now can I add new variable to link and when I will received mail to have link something like this: http://moodle.com/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=132&varialbe=germany&variable2=eu
Note:moodle send email when is activate cron.php script, not when submit replay in replay form.
I hope someone before me already have this issue or have some idea how to find solution, I will really appreciate if He/She want to share with me.

Best Regards,

J.J.

Answer (score 1):

The code is in

```
/mod/forum/lib.php
```

Look for the functions

```
forum_make_mail_text()
```

and

```
forum_make_mail_html()
```

then look for

```
forum/discuss.php
```

in the code.

You can add extra parameters there, good luck! :)